# PHP Error on new RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php

I want to get recursively through a folder and listen the folder in it. I got this code:

```
  $dir_iterator = new    RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../targetdirectory");
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
      echo $file; // this is line 36
     }
```

And I get en error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in ... line 36`

Can somebody please give me a hint. What is the reason for this error;

Comment: "unexpected T_STRING" - you have some invisible/unprintable characters in there. Something that php doesn't see as "spaces" and therefore as a text string without `'` or `"` around it.

Comment: But here is no funny character. Even not in the folder names.

Comment: the contents of the var are irrelevant. the invisible char is in YOUR CODE. delete that line and retype it from scratch. don't copy/paste anything.